# nesting JSON with d3v4 .stratify()

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, d3.js, tree

I am retrieving records from mongodb .find() and trying to nest them with d3v4 .stratify(). Unfortunately, I'm getting the error

> Error: ambiguous: Product Line 1

I'm presuming I'm misunderstanding the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#stratify).

While the problem seems close to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440928/how-do-i-create-a-tree-layout-using-json-data-in-d3-v4-without-stratify), I don't think it's quite the same. However, the result I'm trying to get to IS something [like this](https://bl.ocks.org/mattgiguere/339843b4622a965048fc9f61598f2d47).

Can someone help me understand how to use .stratify() properly? Or suggest an easier way to do this?

My result set (`mongodb_data`) is not large (maybe ~2500 products).

My flat `mongodb_data` looks like this,

```
[
  {
   "name": "Product Line 1",
   "reference": "product 1.A identifier"
  },
  {
   "name": "Product Line 1",
   "reference": "product 1.B identifier"
  },
  {
   "name": "Product Line 2",
   "reference": "product 2.A identifier"
  },
  {
   "name": "Product Line 2",
   "reference": "product 2.B identifier"
  }
];
```

The desired hierarchical/nested data needs to look like this,

```
{
 "name": "Master Product Catalog",
 "children": [
             { 
              "name": "Product Line 1",
              "children": [
                           { "name": "product 1.A identifier" },
                           { "name": "product 1.B identifier" }
                          ]
             },
             { "name": "Product Line 2",
               "children": [
                            { "name": "product 2.A identifier" },
                            { "name": "product 2.B identifier" }
                           ]
             }
             ]
}
```

I have been using the example from the API documentation as follows,

```
var stratdata = d3.stratify() 
                  .id(function(d) { return d.name; }) 
                  .parentId(function(d) { return d.name; }) 
                  (mongodb_data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flat data doesn't represent a hierarchical structure.  It doesn't answer the question who does "Product Line 1" or "Product Line 2" parent to?  Also, your `name` property doesn't hold both the parent and the child information (reference is the parent, name is the child).  Your data before `d3.stratify()` should look like this:

```
[{
  "reference": "Master Product Catalog",
  "name": "" //<-- has no parent
}, {
  "reference": "Product Line 1", 
  "name": "Master Product Catalog" //<-- parent is master
}, {
  "reference": "Product Line 2",
  "name": "Master Product Catalog"
}, {
  "name": "Product Line 1",
  "reference": "product 1.A identifier"
}, {
  "name": "Product Line 1",
  "reference": "product 1.B identifier"
}, {
  "name": "Product Line 2",
  "reference": "product 2.A identifier"
}, {
  "name": "Product Line 2",
  "reference": "product 2.B identifier"
}];
```

---

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var json = [{
      "reference": "Master Product Catalog",
      "name": ""
    }, {
      "reference": "Product Line 1",
      "name": "Master Product Catalog"
    }, {
      "reference": "Product Line 2",
      "name": "Master Product Catalog"
    }, {
      "name": "Product Line 1",
      "reference": "product 1.A identifier"
    }, {
      "name": "Product Line 1",
      "reference": "product 1.B identifier"
    }, {
      "name": "Product Line 2",
      "reference": "product 2.A identifier"
    }, {
      "name": "Product Line 2",
      "reference": "product 2.B identifier"
    }];

    var root = d3.stratify()
      .id(function(d) {
        return d.reference;
      })
      .parentId(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      (json);

    console.log(root)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. It works client side inside my <script> tags. But not server side inside my express.js route. I had hoped to pass in this nested JSON object with the ejs template. Perhaps that's a different question though. Thanks for taking the time on this question.

Comment: `looks like JSON`? Since, JSON is a *string representation* of a JavaScript Object and `root` is a **javascript object**.  I think you meant to ask, "why is `root` not a flat structure of parent/child data?"  The answer is that `d3` adds some additional helper properties and methods to make traversing the structure easier, stratify is creating a [hierarchy object](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.